# How can i send 2 variables through EventHandler

Tags: c#, button, parameters

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game in c# and i'm having problems at checking for the game over subprogram.

```
    int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                b[i, j] = new Button();
                b[i, j].ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                b[i, j].Location = new Point((i * 100) + 25 - i * 10, (j * 100) + 25 - j * 10);
                b[i, j].Size = new Size(60, 60);
                b[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
                b[i, j].Font = new Font("Goudy Old Style", 25);
                this.Controls.Add(b[i, j]);
            }
```

Is it possible to send i, j through the b_click subprogram, for each button?(my game over subprogram work with the parameters i,j)

```
    private void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b =  (Button)sender ;
        if (tura)
            b.Text = Convert.ToString('X');
        else
            b.Text = Convert.ToString('O');
        tura = !tura;
        b.Enabled = false;
        nr_tura++;
        castigator(i,j);
    }
    private void castigator(int i,int j)
    {
        if (game_over(i, j) && tura)
            MessageBox.Show("A castigat X", "Game Over");
        else MessageBox.Show("A castigat O", "Game Over");
        if (nr_tura == 9)
            MessageBox.Show("Remiza", "Game Over");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the button to keep a [`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object with the specified `i` and `j` values of that button.
add this to the loop that creates the button: `b[i, j].Tag = new Point(i, j);`.
And inside the event handler just read them from there like this:

```
Point coordinates = (Point)((Button)sender).Tag;
i = coordinates.X;
j = coordinates.Y;
// ... the rest of your code
```